# How to discern between JSON.NET JArray elements

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm sure the answer to this is extremely simple but I'm having trouble. I have the following JSON string (provided by the Yahoo Fantasy Sports API) that I'm trying to parse into my model objects from a JSON.NET JToken. Because I do not want to litter my project with a bunch of classes specifically to support JSON parsing, I'm trying to do this manually. However, I cannot for my life figure out in the code how to determine whether I'm in the settings case or the teams case. Help?

```
{
   "league":[
      {
         "league_key":"somevalue",
         "name":"My League"
      },
      {
         "teams":{
            "0":{
               "team":[
                  [
                     // some data
                  ]
               ]
            },
            "1":{
               "team":[
                  [
                     // some data
                  ]
               ]
            },
            "count":2
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The following is the code I'm using for parsing (so far):

```
public League ParseJson(JToken token)
{
    var league = new League();
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (var child in token.Children<JObject>())
        {
            // how do I figure out if this child contains the settings or the teams?
        }
        return league;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't want to hardcode it because I might load more/different subresources from a league so it's not guaranteed that it will always contain this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether the child object contains a known property from the subresource you want (which isn't also in one of the other subresources).  Something like this should work.  You can fill in the rest.

```
public League ParseJson(JToken token)
{
    var league = new League();
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (JObject child in token.Children<JObject>())
        {
            if (child["teams"] != null)
            {
                // process teams...
                foreach (JProperty prop in child["teams"].Value<JObject>().Properties())
                {
                    int index;
                    if (int.TryParse(prop.Name, out index))
                    {
                        Team team = new Team();
                        JToken teamData = prop.Value;

                        // (get team data from JToken here and put in team object)

                        league.Teams.Add(team);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (child["league_key"] != null)
            {
                league.Key = child["league_key"].Value<string>();
                league.Name = child["name"].Value<string>();
                // (add other metadata to league object here)
            }
        }
        return league;
    }
    return null;
}

class League
{
    public League()
    {
        Teams = new List<Team>();
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sweet. I noticed that while debugging and using array indexing with non-existing indices, it would throw an exception which is why I didn't think to check for null. But it doesn't do that in the compiled code, so this works.